# How to draw two synchronuous uses cases in a use case diagram?

Tags: uml, synchronized, use-case

I am working on a project where there are 2 actions that will happen at the same time (simultaneously: stream video via pi-camera and take measurements via sensors).
And I intend to draw the use case diagram of this project.
To my knowledge, the concept of parallelism does not exist in use case diagrams.
But just to make sure: **Is it possible to draw synchronous use cases in a use case diagram?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A use case is defined from a users perspective. So if it is the same thing the user wants,it is the same use case. Further, use cases have no notion of execution, thus also no synchronous or asynchronous behavour. Thus this cannot be expressed by use cases intentionally.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought too. The concept of synchronous actions exists in activity diagram.
Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @singrium Beyond this, you can an activity diagram to model the entire behavior of a use case.

Answer (score 2):

As sim says, use cases have no notion of execution, so no notion of synchronous or asynchronous behavior.

However, it's not clear to me that you really need two separate use cases for these two actions in the first place. If they both always occur together, and never individually, they are really one use case, not two, and should be modeled as such.

If you have several other use cases that take sensor measurements, then it might make sense to have a use case for taking the measurements, and have all the other use cases include it (using the `«include»` stereotype). That would be the way to associate them.

Comment: Well explained, thank you. I made them just one use case.